# Issue with handling promise exceptions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, json-server

Hey everyone I am trying to solve a problem statement using Javascript which has a simple button to add movie to favourites in its onclick. The function should throw a `Promise.reject()` if the movie has already been added once in the favourites.

So there are some test cases for this `addFavourite()` and some of the test cases are failing. Can you let me know why ? I can't change the test files so what should I change in my code to resolve the error ?

This is my `addFavourite()` function. (Note: **allMovies** is a list of all movie objects):

```js
function addFavourite(searchId) {
  var favMovie = [];
  allMovies.forEach((iterator) => {
    if (iterator.id == searchId) {
      favMovie = iterator;
    }
  });
  var movieRepeated = false;
  allFavourites.forEach((iterator) => {
    if (iterator.id == favMovie.id) {
      movieRepeated = true;
    }
  });
  if (movieRepeated) {
    return Promise.reject(new Error("Movie repeated!")).then(
      resolved,
      rejected
    );
  } else {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/favourites", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(favMovie),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        }
      })
      .then((addedMovie) => {
        allFavourites.push(addedMovie);
        displayFavs(allFavourites);
        return allFavourites;
      });
  }
}
```

These are the testcases that are failing:

1.

```
it('adding of same movie as favourite twice shall be restricted', (done) => {
        fetchMock.get('http://localhost:3000/movies', moviesTestData);
        fetchMock.get('http://localhost:3000/favourites', favouritesTestData);
        fetchMock.post('http://localhost:3000/favourites', moviesTestData[0]);

        script.getMovies()
        .then(() => {
            return script.getFavourites();
        })
        .then(() => {
            return script.addFavourite(476307);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            expect(err).to.not.equal(null, err);
            expect(err.message).to.equal('Movie is already added to favourites');
            done();
        });
    });
```

2. 

```
it(`addFavourites() shall hit the correct api with correct data and 
        return correct response`, (done) => {
            fetchMock.get('http://localhost:3000/movies', moviesTestData);
            fetchMock.get('http://localhost:3000/favourites', favouritesTestData);
            fetchMock.post('http://localhost:3000/favourites', moviesTestData[0]);

            script.getMovies()
            .then(() => {
                return script.getFavourites();
            })
            .then(() => {
                return script.addFavourite(476307);
            })
            .then((res) => {
                const lastCallArgs = fetchMock.lastCall();
                expect(lastCallArgs[0]).to.equal('http://localhost:3000/favourites');
                expect(lastCallArgs[1].method).to.equal('POST');
                expect(lastCallArgs[1].body).to.equal(JSON.stringify(moviesTestData[0]));
                favouritesTestData.push(moviesTestData[0]);
                expect(res).to.deep.equal(favouritesTestData);
                expect(document.getElementById('favouritesList').innerHTML)
                .to.include('The Unique Lama');
                done();
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                expect(err).to.equal(null, err);
                done();
            });
    });
```

Here is the error that I get:

```
addFavourites() shall hit the correct api with correct data and return correct response:
Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. 
      at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
      at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
```

Comment: You are testing `== favMovie.id`, but `favMovie` is an array and has no `.id` property?!

Comment: "*`.then(resolved, rejected)`*" - this smells like the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)! And notice it returns a promise a that always fulfills, since `rejected` *handles* the error.

Comment: You are missing a `return` in front of the `fetch(…).then(…);` promise chain.

Comment: I initialised favMovie as an array [] by mistake! It's an obiect and is supposed to be {}. Once I traverse throught all the movies and finds the object with the same id, it stores the value of that object.

Comment: Also, I think I need to understand first how promises work, and then I will be able to understand what is going on here! Thanks a lot though.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to call `done()` inside `then` bodies as well, because you are not returning a promise to the test runner.